# Move group of objects (buttons) in each sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have inserted three buttons in each sheet in my Excel spreadsheet and grouped them together with this VBA:

```
Sub Create_New_Buttons()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets

        b.Select
        Dim Button_01 As Button
        Set Button_01 = b.Buttons.Add(423.75, 0, 48, 15)
        Dim Range_Button_01 As Range
        Set Range_Button_01 = b.Range("B2:B4")
        Button_01.Name = "Button_01"
        With Button_01
        .Top = Range_Button_01.Top
        .Left = Range_Button_01.Left
        .Width = Range_Button_01.Width
        .Height = Range_Button_01.Height
        End With

        b.Select
        Dim Button_02 As Button
        Set Button_02 = b.Buttons.Add(423.75, 0, 48, 15)
        Dim Range_Button_02 As Range
        Set Range_Button_02 = b.Range("D2:D4")
        Button_02.Name = "Button_02"
        With Button_02
        .Top = Range_Button_02.Top
        .Left = Range_Button_02.Left
         .Width = Range_Button_02.Width
        .Height = Range_Button_02.Height
        End With

        Rem Combine buttons to group
        Set ButtonList = b.Shapes.Range(Array("Button_01", "Button_02")).Group
        ButtonList.Name = "Button_Group"

Next b

End Sub
```

All this works fine.

---

Now, I want to create a VBA to move this group of buttons in each sheet to `Range("F15:F16")`. 
Therefore, I tried to go with the following VBA:

```
Sub Move_Group_of_Buttons()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = b.Range("F15:F16")
        b.Select
        With Button_Group
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Left = rng.Left
        .Width = rng.Width
        .Height = rng.Height
        End With
Next b
End Sub
```

However, when I run this VBA I get `runtime error  424` on line `.Top = Range.Top`. 
What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: Avoid using `Range` as variable! Replace `Dim Range As Range` with `Dim rng As Range` and adapt the code accordingly.

Comment: Also, where do you set your `ButtonList` within your loop through worksheets?

Comment: `Button_Group` is the name of the group, not an object.

Comment: Replacing `With Button_Group` by `With b.Shapes("Button_Group")` should work, but make sure the "Button_Group" exists.

Comment: Try this. Replace `With Button_Group` with `With b.Shapes("Button_Group")`

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: I tried and the VBA is running without error but the buttons are not moving. They stay at the same position.

Comment: It will work. I just tested it. BTW you can also replace `With Button_Group` with `With ButtonList`

Comment: Weird behaviour on my Excel. I had to restart my computer and open a new "clean" spreadsheet to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 3 scenarios. Take your pick.

---

If you are not sure f the buttons exists and also not sure if they are grouped or not grouped then try this.

**Logic**

If the buttons are already added to the worksheets then use this logic

1. Check if "Button_01", "Button_02" exists
2. Check if they are part of a Group
3. If they are not, group and move
4. If they are then get the name of the grouped shape and move

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Move_Group_of_Buttons()
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim shpA As Shape, shpB As Shape, shp As Shape, ButtonList As Shape
    Dim PartOfGroup As Boolean
    Dim GrpName As String
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Loop through the worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            '~~> set your range
            Set rng = .Range("F15:F16")

            '~~> Check if buttons with that name exists
            On Error Resume Next
            Set shpA = .Shapes("Button_01")
            Set shpB = .Shapes("Button_02")
            On Error GoTo 0

            If shpA Is Nothing Or shpB Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Shapes not found in sheet " & ws.Name
            Else
                PartOfGroup = False
                GrpName = ""

                '~~> Check if the buttons are part of a group
                For Each shp In .Shapes
                    If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
                        For i = 1 To shp.GroupItems.Count
                            If shp.GroupItems(i).Name = "Button_01" Or _
                               shp.GroupItems(i).Name = "Button_02" Then
                                PartOfGroup = True
                                GrpName = shp.Name
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next i
                    End If
                Next shp

                '~~> If part of group
                If PartOfGroup = True Then
                    With .Shapes(GrpName)
                        .Top = rng.Top
                        .Left = rng.Left
                        .Width = rng.Width
                        .Height = rng.Height
                    End With
                Else '<~~ If Not
                    Set ButtonList = .Shapes.Range(Array("Button_01", "Button_02")).Group

                    With ButtonList
                        .Top = rng.Top
                        .Left = rng.Left
                        .Width = rng.Width
                        .Height = rng.Height
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

---

If the buttons exists and are already **grouped** and have the name as `Button_Group` then try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Move_Group_of_Buttons()
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim ButtonList As Shape

    '~~> Loop through the worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            '~~> set your range
            Set rng = .Range("F15:F16")

            Set ButtonList = .Shapes("Button_Group")

            With ButtonList
                .Top = rng.Top
                .Left = rng.Left
                .Width = rng.Width
                .Height = rng.Height
            End With
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

---

If the buttons exists and are **not grouped** then try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Move_Group_of_Buttons()
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim ButtonList As Shape

    '~~> Loop through the worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            '~~> set your range
            Set rng = .Range("F15:F16")

            Set ButtonList = .Shapes.Range(Array("Button_01", "Button_02")).Group

            With ButtonList
                .Top = rng.Top
                .Left = rng.Left
                .Width = rng.Width
                .Height = rng.Height
            End With
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer.